# Refreshing Kendo grid in Angular 2

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

How do you refresh an Angular 2 Kendo grid when the data has been changed?

```
private trash() {
  this.gridView.data.splice(index, 1);
  //I wish to refresh here
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you reassign the modified data to the data property of the grid this will trigger the automatic change detection and everything will work as expected.
e.g.:

```
data.splice(index, 1);
this.gridView.data = data;
```

↑**This is the preferred way to trigger change detection and update the grid.** ↑

Alternatively, if you want to just modify the underlying data you will have to manually notify Angular of the changes.
There are a few ways to trigger change detection in Angular 2. For example, you can inject the ChangeDetector in the constructor of your component and invoke detectChange. Example:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';    

constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    }

    private trash() {
      this.gridView.data.splice(index, 1);
      this.cd.detectChanges()
    }
```

In general I suggest that you read over the web how Angular 2 performs change detection and how to manually trigger it if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I realized it was something else causing the problem after trying your suggestions. I am currently "paging" the grid, and though I was deleting the data from the main "datasource" the individual page was not being updated. Your answer is correct for the way I worded the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
data.splice(index, 1);
this.gridView.data = data;
```

Not working with paging option